# Навигация по html-файлу в Sublime Text

Tags: html, sublime-text, notepad++, работа-с-текстом

В Word можно на любой выделенный текст повесить закладку или заголовок и потом быстро перемещаться по ним в панели навигации. Есть ли такая возможность для Sublime Text/Notepad++, или хотя бы меню навигации по заголовкам ,  и т.д. с их названиями?

Comment: Там есть все... Просто надо изучить и знать горячие клавиши.. А чего нет, можно настроить макросы и снипеты....

Comment: То, что там есть это не то и не так работает. В ворде ты видишь название, в этом отличие. И да, макросы и снипеты не панель навигации.

Answer (score 0):

В Sublime Text Вы можете установить закладки на интересующей строке, комбинация клавиш Ctrl+F2.
Передвигаться по закладкам F2 и Shift+F2, вверх и вниз.
Закладки нужно ставить вручную.